# Constant hard drive processing sounds coming from the laptop

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, noise, system-sounds

My laptop may have recently started making this quiet but noticeable noise. It used to make same noise but more rarely. It is basically the normal hard drive sound, but it's constantly processing something. When I scroll on the mouse it makes that noise as well.

I have an Acer Nitro 515-52 laptop. Is this related to the fan or is there a particle somewhere in the hard drive which causes this sound? It might also be coil whine. No significant programs are playing on the background. My laptop has SSD and HDD drives. I would have recorded it, but for some reason the sound is not picked up by my phone.

There also might be the chance it has always made this noise and I just haven't noticed because of headphones or the fan. The computer is over a year old. I've asked from three other places, but I haven't gotten a solid answer.

Comment: There isnt much to go on here.  You say it may or may not be normal.  You didnt mention any other problems.  Try using a tool like [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/) to read to the drives SMART status.

Comment: "Coil whine" is a distinctive noise, different from normal hard drive sounds, different from the noise of a piece of debris bouncing around inside, and different from a dragging fan.  Describing the sound in text won't get you an answer, particularly if you haven't believed the three places (I assume online) you've asked already.  Bring it to a pro.

Comment: @Keltari i did SMART test and Hard Drive passed it and there haven't been any other problems. It's just the sound i'm worried.

Comment: @Christopher Hostage if it's any more specific it comes from left side of the laptop.

Comment: Please imagine a mechanic, whose neighbor comes to him describing a "whumpty whumpty whumpty" noise.  The neighbor says it's not a "fwee fwee" noise and it's probably not a "woooooop" noise.  The neighbor thinks it's might be a gallstone in the carburetor but it's on the left side.  Also, the neighbor will never consider paying for an expert's help, nor learn how to describe the problem, nor bring the car over to the mechanic so that the mechanic has a chance to hear the problem directly.  This is what's happening in this Question.  Bring it to a pro.